# Xamarin portable class library issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

Hi I have the following issue, I am using xamarin on a Mac and created a cross-platform app solution using native single view app with portable class library.

In the portable class library i added one reference to newtonsoft.json v4.0.3 but when i rebuild my project i get errors like the following:

- Reference to type 'System.ComponentModel.ITypedList' claims it is defined assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', but it could not be found.

What should i do?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is that Json library also portable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 4.0.3 of *Newtonsoft.Json* is only available for .NET (2.0, 3.5, 4.0), Windows Phone 7 (I think) and Silverlight 4. This version does not support *portable class libraries*.

Use *NuGet* to download the latest *Newtonsoft.Json* version, it should provide a number of PCL alternatives, in particular a Profile 328 assembly that can target practically all modern platforms including *Xamarin iOS* and *Android*.